# how to show an IAM user's roles with 'aws iam'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-iam

If I run `$ aws iam get-user --user-name anthony`, I get result like this

```
{
    "User": {
        "Path": "/",
        "UserName": "anthony",
        "UserId": "E2S4XZIL9NRNSBIDBI5U6",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456:user/anthony",
        "CreateDate": "2015-04-03T01:22:11Z",
        "PasswordLastUsed": "2019-04-10T01:38:14Z"
    }
}
```

If I want to get a list of `role` this login has, how can I do it with `aws iam`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*IAM User* doesn't have *IAM Roles*, hence you can't list them.

*IAM User* can have **IAM Policies** (either attached directly or through *IAM Group* membership) that allow it to **assume other roles**.

You can list directly attached policies:

```
aws iam list-attached-user-policies --user-name ...
```

Group memberships:

```
aws iam list-groups-for-user --user-name ...
```

And from there groups policies:

```
aws iam list-attached-group-policies --group-name ... # group names from previous step
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly with AWS cli tool it is not possible to list all roles a user can assume. As a workaround you can list all roles with associated users and search for your user in this output.

The following command lists all roles and filters (via jq tool) for role name and associated users:

```
aws iam list-roles --output=json | jq '.Roles[] |  {role: .RoleName, user: .AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS} | select(.user != null)'
```

Example output:

```
{
  "role": "dev-ops-rw",
  "user": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/user1"
} 
{
  "role": "finance",
  "user": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/user2"
}
{
  "role": "service",
  "user": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/user1"
}
```

This output shows that *user1* can assume the roles *dev-ops-rw* and *service*. The user *user2* can assume the role *finance*.

Answer (score 0):

First do:

aws iam list-user-policies --user-name USER

Than do:

aws iam get-user-policy --user-name USER --policy-name POLICY-NAME-FOUND-ABOVE